# How to block all traffic after repeated connections on one port?

Tags: iptables

In the manpage for `iptables-extensions`, there is an example given that shows how to block all traffic from an IP address that tries to connect on port 139:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m recent --name badguy --rcheck --seconds 60 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 139 -m recent --name badguy --set -j DROP
```

I'm trying to modify this so that if someone connects too frequently on port 22, they will also be completely blocked - all traffic - for some time, but a few initial connections are allowed.  I don't however want to block any existing active connections, just block new connections.

I have tried this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eno3 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 300 --reap --hitcount 3 --name sshthrottle -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eno3 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name sshthrottle -p tcp --dport 22
```

However now what happens is that incoming connections on *any* port trigger the block, so for example after three connections on port 80, the IP is blocked for 300 seconds.  I don't want the block to activate when any port is connected to, only when port 22 is connected to.

What am I doing wrong?

(FYI I am aware that there are examples on Google for throttling SSH traffic, but they all duplicate the `--dport` rule on the `--rcheck` line which means only SSH traffic will get blocked, whereas I want to block connections to all ports once triggered.  My problem is not with the block - traffic is successfully blocked - but with the trigger, that I only want port 22 to trigger the block not all ports.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok worked out what it is.  I didn't realise that the order of the parameters on the `iptables` command line makes a difference.

I had this:

```
-m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name sshthrottle -p tcp --dport 22
```

Which says:

1. If the state is NEW
2. SET (add) to the sshthrottle list of IPs
3. Then check if the connection is to port 22
4. Do nothing and continue with then next rule

So of course it was checking if it was port 22 *after* it had added the IP to the list.

Changing the order to this works:

```
-m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --set --name sshthrottle
```

Which of course translates to:

1. If the state is NEW
2. And the TCP port is 22
3. Then SET (add) to the sshthrottle list of IPs
4. Do nothing and continue with the next rule

The key of course being that the `--set` parameter adds the IP to the list as soon as it is encountered, so it should be one of the last parameters on the command line to work as expected.

Really the `--set` parameter should be a target (e.g. `-j SETRECENT`) since normally only targets do something, which is why for example `-j LOG` is a target and not a `--log` parameter.